# Is $\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$ Cauchy in $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am extremely out of practice in figuring out convergence of sequences/series - I want to figure out if 
$$\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$$
is a Cauchy sequence in $n$ when $x\in [0,1]$, that is, if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an integer $N$ such that for all $n,m \ge N$, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k^2} - \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{x^k}{k^2}.$$
So far, all I have is that if $m >n$, we have
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{x^k}{k^2},$$
and I've also thought of trying to look at when $x = 1$, which gives us
$$\sum^m_{k=n+1}\frac{1}{k^2},$$
and maybe if that sequence converges, then the sequence will converge for all $x\in [0,1]$. Problem being that even though I think that $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, I don't know how to handle the fact that the starting index is $0$.

Am I on the right track at all? Am I totally wrong? Thanks.

Comment: $k=0$ must be a mistake, it makes the sum undefined.

Comment: As you noticed, the series doesn't make sense because the summand is undefined for $k=0$. Starting at $k=1$ produces a series that you can deal with in the way you suggest.

Comment: Thank you, both of you, I thought it might be a mistake, but I am so rusty with sequences/series I was worried that I was missing something important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the starting index 0 is a typo.

We have: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k^2} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}< \infty$. Your infinite sum is convergent, thus is Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that

$$\text{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^2}$$

for $|x|\le 1$ is the series representation of the dilogarithm function.  The series converges on the interval of interest absolutely and uniformly.

Inasmuch as a sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence, then convergence alone of the series implies that its partial sum constitutes a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Interesting, I don't remember this dilogarithm function, but thank you for this alternative approach!

Comment: @poppy3345 You're welcome.  The dilogarithm has the integral representation $\text{Li}_2(z)=-\int_0^z\frac{\log(1-u)}{u}\,du$ for all complex $z$ except those $z$ with $\text{Re}(z)\ge 1$ and $\text{Im}(z)=0$ (i.e., on the real line from $x\ge 1$).